# Realm Swift adding object with String property having character count > 1874 is crashing

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a csv file with 200K rows.

each row contains 9 values, all the rows String character count is less than 2048 but 3 rows have character count equal to 4420. These rows indexes are 134481, 134482, 134483 respectively. Out of the 9 values in the row last string value is big.

When row 134481 is adding to realm or creating in realm, it get crashed at BpTree::create_root_from_mem with EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=xxxxx)

Below is the swift code [swift version 2.2, xcode: 7.3, realmSwift: 1.1.0]...for adding the csv objects to realm database.

This code is running in a background queue. I tried skipping first 130k rows and even then it crashes exactly at row 134481. Only after reducing the string character count the object is added without crash.

```
class PackageObject:Object {
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var packageBatch = ""
    dynamic var packageCode = ""
    dynamic var packageDescription = ""
    dynamic var packageName = ""
    dynamic var packagelocalName = ""
    dynamic var packageNumber = ""
    dynamic var packageBuild = ""
    dynamic var packageSummary = ""
}

let filename = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("codes", ofType: "tsv")
    if let realm = try? Realm(configuration: configuration), data = try? String.init(contentsOfFile: filename!) {
        let block = 5000
        var lineNumber = 0
        print(realm.configuration.fileURL)

        data.enumerateLines({ (line, stop) in
            if lineNumber % block == 0 {
                print("begin: ", lineNumber)
                realm.beginWrite()
            }
            lineNumber += 1
            var strings = line.componentsSeparatedByString("\t")

            if lineNumber >= 134481 && lineNumber <= 134483 {
                // strings[8] count is about 3805
                // after reducing the count to 1874, the object
                // is successfully added to the realm, else a crash is observed.
                let count = strings[8].characters.count
                print(count, line.characters.count)
                let index = strings[8].endIndex.advancedBy(1931 - count)
                strings[8].removeRange(index..<strings[8].endIndex)
            }

            let packageObj = PackageObject(value: strings)
            realm.add(packageObj)
            //realm.create(PackageObject.self, value:strings)
            if lineNumber % block == 0 {
                print("commit: ", lineNumber)
                _ = try? realm.commitWrite()
            }
        })
    }

   // The last commitWrite is not handled...inside the block.
   // for the below condition...
   if lineNumber % block != 0 {
       _ = try? realm.commitWrite()
   }
```

The realm doc says a String property can be less than 16MB, but here its not even taking 10KB.

I don't find anything wrong with the string, it is just plain English text. Is this a bug or do I have to add objects in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string property is indexed, upgrading to 2.0 will probably fix this.

Older versions had a flaw in how the index was implemented that lead to it hitting a stack overflow when strings have sufficiently long common prefixes, and 2.0 changed how indexes are stored to remove the recursion.

Comment: That exactly what is happening it seems, as I have an index on it and they do have long common prefixes. is RealmSwift 2.0 available for Swift 2.3.